# Can we save keras model as a binary file in python?

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, bytesio

I have the keras sequential model, normal way of saving is

```
from keras.models import load_model
keras_model.save('classifier_keras.h5')
classifier_keras = load_model('classifier_keras.h5')
```

If I need to store in a database as encoded file, how to convert keras model as binary?

Comment: Every file is a binary file essentially. You do can open it as a binary file `open("classifier_keras.h5", "rb")`.

Comment: .h5 is a binary file, not sure what you are asking exactly.

Comment: Thanks, I need to convert the binary to base64 to save in the database, looking for conversion without saving to disk

Answer (score 0):

```
HDF5 "model.h5"
h5dump -a /layer_names -a /dense_1/weight_names -d /dense_1/dense_1/bias:0 -b LE -o dset.model.bin model.h5
```